# Create S4 slots dynamically

Tags: r, r-s4

I would like to create (or extend) slots of a defined S4 class dynamically, where slots names and types are stored in a variable.

A manual approach would be:

```
setClass("ClassA", representation(
   Slot1 = "character",
   Slot2 = "numeric",
   Slot3 = "character"
))
```

But I would like to retrieve slot names and types from a variable:

```
slotName <- list("slot1", "slot2", "slot3")
slotType <- list("character", "numeric", "character")
slots <- map2(slotName, slotType, ~ str_c(.x, "=", '"',  .y, '"'))
```

How can I create the class with NSE?

I tried with `eval(parse_expr())` to quote the expression within the class definition:

```
y <- str_c(slotName[1], "=", '"', slotType[1], '"')

setClass("classA", representation(
    eval(parse_expr(y))
))

x <- new("classA")
```

But here the structure of the object `x` is:

```
> str(x)
Formal class 'classA' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 1 slot
  ..@ .Data: chr(0)`
```

with no `slot1`, unfortunately.  Mapping vectors in the class definition did not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to set names of parameters, the better strategy is to build a named list and use `do.call` to run a function. It's best to avoid `eval()`; there are almost always better options. In this case you can do

```
setClass("ClassA", 
  do.call("representation", setNames(slotType, slotName))
)

x <- new("ClassA") 
str(x)
# Formal class 'ClassA' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 3 slots
#   ..@ slot1: chr(0) 
#   ..@ slot2: num(0) 
#   ..@ slot3: chr(0)
```